# r categorize non-zero data by median

Tags: r

My data set is like below;

```
ID  Quantity
1   0.93
2   0.17
3   NA
4   0.44
5   NA
6   0.86
7   0.07
8   0.23
9   1.00
```

Now, I want to categorize all non-zero/non-NA data in column 'Quantity' into <=median value and >median value. The 'NA' should be considered as '0'. So, for the above data median is '0.44' therefore, the final data set should look like;

```
ID  Quantity    Quantity_median
1   0.93        >0.44
2   0.17        <=0.44
3   NA          0
4   0.44        <=0.44
5   NA          0
6   0.86        >0.44
7   0.07        <=0.44
8   0.23        <=0.44
9   1.00        >0.44
```

Comment: Try with `cut`  and quantile

Comment: I don't see how `0.44` can be the median of that column, either removing `NA` values, or replacing them with 0.

Comment: You can check by `quantile(df1$Quantity, na.rm = TRUE)[3]`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I am removing NA values

Comment: This is essentially just `dat$Quantity > 0.44` with a few labels added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since, number of possible levels are only 3 hence, you can try something like:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% mutate(Qmedian = median(Quantity, na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
      mutate(Quantity_median =  as.factor(case_when(
                                 is.na(Quantity) ~ "0",
                                 Quantity <= Qmedian ~ paste0("<=", Qmedian),
                                 Quantity >= Qmedian ~ paste0(">", Qmedian)
                                      ))) %>%
    select(-Qmedian)

#  ID Quantity Quantity_median
# 1  1     0.93           >0.44
# 2  2     0.17          <=0.44
# 3  3       NA               0
# 4  4     0.44          <=0.44
# 5  5       NA               0
# 6  6     0.86           >0.44
# 7  7     0.07          <=0.44
# 8  8     0.23          <=0.44
# 9  9     1.00           >0.44
```

Comment: That was just perfect @MKR

Answer (score 2):

We could use `cut` as well

```
m1 <- median(df1$Quantity, na.rm = TRUE)
lbls <- paste0(c("<=", ">"), m1)
df1$Quantity_median <-  with(df1, as.character(cut(Quantity, breaks = 2, labels = lbls)))
df1$Quantity_median[is.na(df1$Quantity_median)] <- 0
df1
#  ID Quantity Quantity_median
#1  1     0.93           >0.44
#2  2     0.17          <=0.44
#3  3       NA               0
#4  4     0.44          <=0.44
#5  5       NA               0
#6  6     0.86           >0.44
#7  7     0.07          <=0.44
#8  8     0.23          <=0.44
#9  9     1.00           >0.44
```